# How do I write a jpeg2000 with a transparent background in Java?

Tags: java, jai, jpeg2000

I'm using Java Advanced Imaging to read and write `JPEG2000` images in java.  When debugging in Intellij, I can view the `BufferedImage` and see that it's transparent. So I can stack layers on top of each other.  But when I write it to a file, the background is always black.  Is it something I'm doing wrong? Or is it the writer that's the problem? Do I need to be doing something specific with the `J2KImageWriteParam` regarding encoding etc?  Unfortunately I'm fairly new to handling images programmatically, and there is little to no information or support for `jpeg2000` that I can find.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jp2"));
BufferedImage tmpImage = new BufferedImage(
    image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR_PRE
);
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) tmpImage.getGraphics();
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
ImageIO.write(tmpImage, "jpeg2000", new File("outputImage.jp2"));
g.dispose();
```

Comment: Do you need the file format to be JPEG2000? The JPEG2000 format does allow for alpha channel, but I'm not sure if the JAI ImageIO plugin supports it. Try using a different format, like PNG or TIFF, to see if that works.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it does need to JPEG2000.  PNG, TIFF, GIF all work just fine.  It seems from all the testing I've done, that the JAI writer writes the alpha channel in a way that only the JAI reader understands.  All of the viewers I've used just see the black background.  But when I read in a file I've written with a test program, the image shows transparent in the debugger.